# SBS 2011 Group policy won't update/apply properly

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, windows-sbs-2011

i'm running SBS 2011 on a dell poweredge t110 II, and recently i've found that i am unable to apply/update group policies. I get the following error:

> The processing of Group Policy failed. Windows attempted to read the file \abs.
>   local\SysVol\abs.local\Policies{8CF7D16A-2A7C-4E08-AF33-4A04ABDF9411}\gpt.ini f
>   rom a domain controller and was not successful. Group Policy settings may not be
>    applied until this event is resolved. This issue may be transient and could be
>   caused by one or more of the following:
>   a) Name Resolution/Network Connectivity to the current domain controller.
>   b) File Replication Service Latency (a file created on another domain controller
>    has not replicated to the current domain controller).
>   c) The Distributed File System (DFS) client has been disabled.
>   Computer policy could not be updated successfully. The following errors were enc
>   ountered:
>   The processing of Group Policy failed. Windows attempted to read the file \abs.
>   local\SysVol\abs.local\Policies{8CF7D16A-2A7C-4E08-AF33-4A04ABDF9411}\gpt.ini f
>   rom a domain controller and was not successful. Group Policy settings may not be
>    applied until this event is resolved. This issue may be transient and could be
>   caused by one or more of the following:
>   a) Name Resolution/Network Connectivity to the current domain controller.
>   b) File Replication Service Latency (a file created on another domain controller
>    has not replicated to the current domain controller).
>   c) The Distributed File System (DFS) client has been disabled.
>   To diagnose the failure, review the event log or run GPRESULT /H GPReport.html f
>   rom the command line to access information about Group Policy results.

However the file to which it refers, "8CF7D16A-2A7C-4E08-AF33-4A04ABDF9411" doesn't exist.

Is there any way i can get group policy to stop trying to look for this and so update correctly?

Comment: Yes. Delete the GPO link and alternately the GPO itself.

Comment: Where do i find the GPO link? When i follow the directory path it indicates, there is nothing there. The entire directory doesn't exist.

Comment: I'm not talking about the file system object for the GPO, I'm talking about the AD object for the GPO, which can be found in the GPMC. Select each GPO, select the details tab and find the GPO whose Unique ID matches the one in the event log entry. Your problem sounds like the AD GPO component exists but the file system GPO component is missing. - http://gpoguy.com/whitepapers/understanding-group-policy-storag/

Comment: Ahhh thanks. It's the update services common settings profile which is invalid. Since we use WSUS, is there a way i can restore the GPO in the filesystem?

Comment: It will probably be easier to create a new GPO with those settings. In the GPMC navigate to the Group Policy Objects node, find and right click the GPO in question and select "Copy" then right click the Group Policy Objects node and select "Paste". Select "Preserve existing permissions" when prompted. This will create a GPO with the name "Copy of blahblahblah". You can then link this GPO to the same locations as the original GPO, unlink the original GPO, delete the original GPO and rename the new GPO.